# Funnel chart with bars separated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

what is the best way to create funnel chart with bars separated and as a funnel (as below image- click image link) using css, html, javascript.

[image]

Comment: Where is the data for the funnel going to come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use amcharts to create charts. They're easy to use and beautiful to look at. Do give them a try :)

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/funnel-chart/

I created a plunker link so that you can see how this works and maybe explore it a little bit.

https://plnkr.co/edit/tp6oOpoxChMoYlpwEroC?p=preview

All you need in you html is this

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

If you want to go for something even more visually appealing, you can use 3d funnel charts that amcharts provides.

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/3d-funnel-chart/

Comment: But i need to buy licence of amcharts.com for it if i need to use for my company project, looking for open source code or develop myself.

Comment: amcharts is open source. You dont need to buy it. Check out the the plunker link i created to see how it works. This will save you lots of time and creating the chart will be super easy

Comment: you can download it for free from their website https://www.amcharts.com/download/

Comment: D3.js have similar chart